# Javascript calling functions in array by window[string]

Tags: javascript, function, window

```
function foobar(){
    alert("Hello World");
}


var funcName = "foobar";
var func = window[funcName];
if (typeof func === "function" ) func();
```

Hello! I would like to call function like above

```
var functions = {
    function1 : function(){ return },
    function2 : function(){ return },
    function3 : function(){ return },
    function4 : function(){ return }
}
```

with the object of functions.

I've tried

```
window["functions.function1"] // or
window["functions['function1']"]
```

and they don't work! How can I achieve this?
Thank you!

edited: "with the array of functions." to "with the object of functions."

Comment: That's not an array. That's an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with your concept of using strings, it would be:

```
window["functions"]["function1"]();
```

If you want a single string for it, you can use `split` and walk through the parts:

```
var name = "functions.function1";
callFunction(name);

function callFunction(name) {
    var parts = name.split(".");
    var n;
    var obj = window;
    for (n = 0; n < parts.length; ++n) {
         obj = obj[parts[n]];
         if (!obj) {
             return;
         }
    }
    return obj ? obj() : undefined;
}
```

---

Side note: All properties of `window` are a globals. The global namespace is *incredibly* crowded, so adding more globals is a Bad Idea<sup>(tm)</sup>. Instead, wrap your code in a scoping function and use your own object rather than `window`.